# Add item to RadDropDownList at index 0

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I have a Rad dropdown which is populated from the DB.
I need to add the first item, index 0 but I am not winning.

```
public  void FillDropDownList(string connString)
    {
        String query = "......";
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            cn.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(myReader);
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
               //TODO
            }
            radDropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
            radDropDownList1.ValueMember = "...";
            radDropDownList1.DisplayMember = "....";
        }
        radDropDownList1.Items.Add(0,"Select a table...");//this does not work
    }
```

The index "0," gives me error "Unknow method insert (int, string).

How do I add an item at index 0 in such dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add items like that. You need to create a `list of strings` first:

```
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
```

add a string in the list

```
strList.Add("....");
```

and finally add *strList* to `radDropDownList1`:

```
radDropDownList1.Items.AddRange(strList);
```

**EDIT**

So, you don't want to add an item but to change an existing one:

```
radDropDownList1.Items[0].Text = "Select a table...";
```

Comment: Thanks. it has the same effect of my line of code without the index, I mean: radDropDownList1.Items.Add("Select a table..."); I need to make sure that the added item is the first one, index 0, on top of the other items populated from the DB. I have updated my question to show the entire method.

Comment: :-)) Thats it. Your update works fine. I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the element to your query, and that would be the easier way:

```
SELECT 0 ORDER, "First Element" FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 1 ORDER, FIELD_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CODITION = VALUE
ORDER BY ORDER
```

(this assuming Oracle as database, you have similar syntax in other)

Otherwise you can add it to the DataTable after the query and before associating the Datatable to the Dropdownlist.

Or you can also add it on the databind event of the dropdonwlist

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a radcombobox instead, it has a property that accomplishes what I think you are after called "EmptyMessage"

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select a table...">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```